# Export data from listbox to Excel [C#]

Tags: c#, excel, wpf

I have a problem because I can't export data from a listbox to Excel. I tried a lot of ways to do this but nothing happened. In Excel, I get only `Excel.Kontrahenci` (name of class) but I need export name of company to Excel.

[image: IMG1]

```
List<Kontrahenci> name = new List<Kontrahenci>();

private void UpdateBinding()
{
    listBox.ItemsSource = name;
    listBox.DisplayMemberPath = "Info";
    listBox1.DisplayMemberPath = "Info";
}

public void Open()
{
    Excel1.Application excel = new Excel1.Application();
    Excel1.Workbook workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open("D:\\Test.xlsx");
    Excel1.Worksheet sheet = (Excel1.Worksheet)workbook.Sheets["Arkusz1"];
    sheet.Select();

    Excel1.Worksheet x = excel.ActiveSheet as Excel1.Worksheet;

    Excel1.Range userRange = x.UsedRange;
    int countRecords = userRange.Rows.Count;
    int add = countRecords + 1;

    x.Cells[add, 1] = listBox.SelectedItem.ToString();

    workbook.Save();
    workbook.Close();
    excel.Quit();
}
```

Comment: Why would you need `x` variable when you have `sheet` variable?

Comment: There's no problem, you just need to understand how `ToString` works, hence the duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override `ToString` method in your class like this:

```
class Customer
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() { return $"{FirstName} {LastName}"; }
}
```